# Error getting /pets: null for uri

Tags: cassandra, usergrid

I encountered this issue when trying to insert the following JSON to pets collection from the admin portal.

{
  "name": "Piranha",
  "species": "Fish",
  "place": "Amazon River"
}

Error message:
error getting /pets: null for uri: http://localhost:8080/myfirstorg/myapp//pets?ql=order%20by%20modified%20DESC%20order%20by%20created%20desc&access_token=YWMtbiR60KXcEeSrJ4WjiQvKxQAAAUtNrv1T-bU4GA073ysLJz-czaSTPdsczfM

Can someone tell me what the problem is?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an extra forward slash in the URL between myapp and pets. A bug ticket needs to be filed in the Apache Usergrid jira. I can do this.